# Amcharts: Gantt - duration in float

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Is it possible to enter duration in floats, `for example, 0.89`

My fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/sachinpsingh/36xqwskf/1/

I tried but it seems to accept only integer values.

The Code -

```
AmCharts.useUTC = true;
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "gantt",
  "theme": "light",
  "period": "fff",
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS",
  "balloonDateFormat": "QQQ",
  "columnWidth": 0.5,
  "marginBottom": 30,
  "valueAxis": {
    "type": "date",
    "minPeriod": "fff",
    "ignoreAxisWidth": true
  },
  "brightnessStep": 10,
  "graph": {
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "balloonText": "<b>[[task]]</b>: [[duration]]ms"
  },
  "rotate": true,
  "categoryField": "category",
  "segmentsField": "segments",
  "colorField": "color",
  "startDate": "2015-01-01 00:00:00",
  "startField": "start",
  "endField": "end",
  "durationField": "duration",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "category": "John",
    "segments": [{
      "start": 7,
      "duration": 2,
      "color": "#46615e",
      "task": "Task #1"
    }, {
      "duration": 2,
      "color": "#727d6f",
      "task": "Task #2"
    }, {
      "duration": 2,
      "color": "#8dc49f",
      "task": "Task #3"
    }]
  }, {
    "category": "Smith",
    "segments": [{
      "start": 10,
      "duration": 2,
      "color": "#727d6f",
      "task": "Task #2"
    }, {
      "duration": 1,
      "color": "#8dc49f",
      "task": "Task #3"
    }, {
      "duration": 4,
      "color": "#46615e",
      "task": "Task #1"
    }]
  }],
  "valueScrollbar": {
    "autoGridCount": true
  },
  "chartCursor": {
    "cursorColor": "#55bb76",
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "valueLineAlpha": 0.5,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "zoomable": false,
    "valueZoomable": true
  }
});
```

When I define "duration": 4.88, it shows in the chart as "duration": 4 (only integer value).

I want that it should show 4.88 as the size in chart.

Comment: Please use the built-in Code Snippet feature.
Also, please clarify what you mean by _enter a duration_

Comment: You can find 'duration' in "dataProvider" JSON, please have a look in my fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution -

just need to replace the `"type": "date",` to `"type": "time",`

just as below -

```
"valueAxis": {
    "type": "time",
    "minPeriod": "fff",
    "ignoreAxisWidth": true
  }
```

It Works!